# DependencyObject SetValue vs Property accessor

Tags: wpf

DependencyObjects can have SetValue() available and most (if not all) of WPF's stock UIElement derived controls contain DependencyObject properties than can be set via SetValue. Sometimes it is practical to do code-behind in a WPF application. Below produces similar result. But which one is better?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Loaded="myTextBlock_Loaded"/>
```

And setting the Text property can be done in two ways.

```
myTextBlock.Text = "foo";
```

OR

```
myTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "foo");
```

Maybe the difference is trivial but I'm curious whether there is an advantage of using the one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight performance boost* in the second, as the implementation of `TextBlock.Text` set is actually `return this.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, value);`.

However it should be noted that it is possible to get the second implementation wrong, for example you could end up typing

```
myTextBlock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, "foo");
```

Which would compile, but likely not run (or at least not give the expected result).

Further, the former will give you type-safety that the later would not give.

*"This performance boost" should however be JITed away.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency properties with actual properties are essentially conveniences to get or set those properties through code.  All dependency properties for all dependency objects are backed by a "dictionary" of key/values.  Those values are accessed through the `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` methods.

What is "better" all depends on how you intend to use the properties.  All builtin controls define properties to make it easier to initialize the objects through code.  It would be far messier if you tried the same using the Get/Set methods.

But *don't* look at it in terms of what is "better," you'll get nowhere thinking in that way. Both are necessary. The dependency properties are how you get/set observable properties of dependency objects.  Making those properties accessible with corresponding properties makes using your code easier.

If you don't need to access these dependency properties through code, then I suppose you could argue that the properties are not needed, but then *nobody* would want to use it.

Comment: Leaning towards code-behind and maybe binding somewhere else. The former is for handling some minor events to avoid add'l codes in VM. That's the intention.